# Cannot find symbol if statement error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, symbols

I have been coding a small program for fun, but I have been getting this error:

```
Compilation error   time: 0.11 memory: 380672 signal:0Main.java:22: 
error: cannot find symbol
            string dtext = "One";
        ^
  symbol:   class string
  location: class Ideone
Main.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(dtext);
                       ^
  symbol:   variable dtext
  location: class Ideone
2 errors
```

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

class Ideone
{
public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //System.out.println("Please enter the month of birth");
    //int month = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the day of birth");
    int day = sc.nextInt();

    //day num to day text
    if (day == 1)
    {
        string dtext = "One";
    }
    else if (day == 2)
    {
        string dtext = "Two";
    }
    else if (day == 3)
    {
        string dtext = "Three";
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error, day incorrect.");
    }

    System.out.println(dtext);
}
}
```

I did some research and found that java cannot find the string variable, but why?
The variable is defined and, the print statement is correct.

Comment: Java iS CaSe SenSiTivE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `string` class in java. There is [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class.

```
string dtext = "Two";
```

should be

```
   String dtext = "Two";
```

`S` must be capital.

And have a look on your String `variable` scope. You are restricted it to If `block`.Move it to top,

Then your code look like

```
String dtext = "";
        if (day == 1) {
            dtext = "One";
        } else if (day == 2) {
            dtext = "Two";
        } else if (day == 3) {
            dtext = "Three";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error, day incorrect.");
        }
        System.out.println(dtext);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo

```
String dtext = "One";
```

Look at [String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

One more thing check the [variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

```
if (day == 1)
{
    String dtext = "One";  //it dtext has local scope here
}//after this line dtext is not available
```

declare `dtext` outside `if` as

```
String dtext = "";
 if (day == 1)
 {
    dtext = "One";
 }
 else if (day == 2)
 {
    dtext = "Two";
 }
 else if (day == 3)
 {
    dtext = "Three";
 }
 else
 {
    System.out.println("Error, day incorrect.");
 }

System.out.println(dtext);
```

Answer (score 1):

string doesn't exist in java. Your `string` first letter should be capital ->  `String`

eg

change `string dtext = "One";` to `String dtext = "One";`

From your code

```
if (day == 1)
{
    string dtext = "One";
}
else if (day == 2)
{
    string dtext = "Two";
}
else if (day == 3)
{
    string dtext = "Three";
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Error, day incorrect.");
}

System.out.println(dtext);      //this line will get error dtext variable in not reachable.
```

Your code need to look like below

```
String dtext ="";
if (day == 1)
{
    dtext = "One";
}
else if (day == 2)
{
    dtext = "Two";
}
else if (day == 3)
{
    dtext = "Three";
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Error, day incorrect.");
}
System.out.println(dtext);
```